Execute a task after waking up from Suspend/sleep
Info
Fedora 40, Gnome 46, Wayland
systemctl --version
systemd 255 (255.6-1.fc40)

notify-send --version
notify-send 0.8.3

Task
I want to execute the following task after waking up from Suspend/sleep, it shows the duration of suspend in a notify-send desktop notification.
mapfile -t UnixDate < <(journalctl -o short-iso --since "24 hours ago" | grep systemd-sleep | tail -n 2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -L 1 date +%s -d)
if (("${#UnixDate[@]}" == 2)); then
    Duration="$(python -c "import datetime; time=(${UnixDate[1]} - ${UnixDate[0]})/3600; print(str(datetime.timedelta(hours=time)))")"
    notify-send \
        --app-name="Suspend" \
        --icon=face-smile \
        --urgency=normal \
        --expire-time=3000 \
        --hint int:transient:1 \
        "Slept" "${Duration}"
fi

What I tried?

Refer:

man systemd-suspend.service
Running scripts before and after suspend with systemd – Just another Linux geek



$ pwd
/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep

$ ls -la
total 4.0K
755 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 574 2024-05-19 09:24 Suspend_notification.sh

$\cat Suspend_notification.sh  
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
        journalctl -o short-iso --since "24 hours ago" | grep systemd-sleep | tail -n 2
        mapfile -t UnixDate < <(journalctl -o short-iso --since "24 hours ago" | grep systemd-sleep | tail -n 2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -L 1 date +%s -d)
        if (("${#UnixDate[@]}" == 2)); then
                Duration="$(python -c "import datetime; time=(${UnixDate[1]} - ${UnixDate[0]})/3600; print(str(datetime.timedelta(hours=time)))")"
                notify-send \
                        --app-name="Suspend" \
                        --icon=face-smile \
                        --urgency=critical \
                        "Slept" "${Duration}"
        fi
fi


Does it need to be via notify-send? That complicates things significantly since that can only be done easily by processes belonging to your user since anyone else would need to be given a way to access your GUI session.

@terdon Gnome on Fedora already has notify-send server installed. Is there any issues with notify-send? I am using notify-send 0.8.3

It's not a question of version, but of having systemd access your running X/Wayland session. You also need to make sure it waits until the session is active before running, but basically, it is never trivial to have something external connect to your user's GUI session. I've never tried it with Wayland, but I imagine it will be the same basic idea where you need to set various variables. See, for example, here for a case using cron and X: Using notify-send with cron

What you tried doesn't work because certain environment variables are only known to processes running outside of the "desktop session" context. Environment is not global – it's inherited down a process subtree, and things like your personal DISPLAY or XAUTHORITY aren't known by system-wide services.
(More so because there can be more than one user and/or more than one display per system! This is something not to forget on Unix.SE of all places.)
These days, the general problem of "running desktop stuff from outside desktop context" is easy to solve by calling systemd-run --user, which relies on the user's service manager already having all necessary environment variables:
systemd-run -M pine@.host --user --collect notify-send "Hello world" &

or, with older systemd versions:
sudo -u pine XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u pine) \
    systemd-run --user --collect notify-send "Hello world" &

Without systemd --user, you would have to make your desktop session collect the basic environment variables into a file (e.g. ~/.env), then have your script load them (e.g. by source-ing the file). The most important ones for notify-send would be XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. (But not DISPLAY, as the tool does not make use of X11 nor Wayland in any way – all it does is talk via D-Bus to an already-running X11 notification applet.)
...on that note, with systemd, the D-Bus session bus is at a fixed location so you don't normally need DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS anyway; libdbus will automatically determine it from XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. And since that's fixed, your script can just do:
sudo -u pine XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u pine) \
    notify-send "Hello world" &

But this won't work for X11 apps, which need more environment variables, so keep all three of the above examples for reference.

A related problem is that GNOME and systemd have a new feature that freezes user processes (using cgroup freezer facility) before suspend and thaws them after resume. I've not looked any deeper into it other than "saw on GitHub that it now exists", so I don't know whether it'll affect your script, but it might be that the systemd-sleep hooks run while the user session processes are still frozen.
With process freezing, the above might still work from a systemd-sleep hook – it will make the D-Bus connection anyway, and the dbus-daemon will react to it later (that's the reason for the & in the above examples though) – or you might need a different approach entirely.
The most correct approach would be to use the opposite architecture; instead of a system service "poking into" the desktop session, have the desktop session listen to a system service's sleep/wake notifications. This should be possible here, as systemd-logind actually broadcasts such notifications over D-Bus, and it would completely avoid all of the above problems as your "listener" program – being run as part of your the GUI – would already have all necessary environment.
[I'll post a script for this later if I remember]
(Similar to the way polkit-agent works; it's not polkitd that displays the GUI password prompt, it's a GUI app that waits for polkitd to indicate "password prompt needed".)

On a side note:

mapfile -t UnixDate < <(journalctl -o short-iso --since "24 hours ago" | grep systemd-sleep | tail -n 2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -L 1 date +%s -d)


This is extremely inefficient. The journal is an indexed database, so if you need a specific message by program name – or by message ID, or any other field – you can request it directly, without having to grep 24 hours' worth of messages:
msg=$(journalctl -o json -b -n 1 MESSAGE_ID=6bbd95ee977941e497c48be27c254128)

unixtime=$(jq -r .__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP <<< "$msg")

absdate=$(date -d "@$unixtime")

or if you prefer,
absdate=$(journalctl -o short-iso -b -n 1 \
              MESSAGE_ID=6bbd95ee977941e497c48be27c254128 \
          | awk '{print $1}')

(I got the message ID from journalctl -t systemd-sleep -o verbose, as I happened to write a similar script myself just last week.)
